# Google Sheets Apps Script - set all blank cells in a column to zero

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a novice when it comes to macros or Google Sheets Apps Script. I'm trying to write a Google Sheets macro to reformat data periodically exported from a website. So far I've figured out most of it, but I'm getting stuck trying to find all blank cells in certain columns (ignoring the header row) and set them to zero. Here's what I have so far:

```
function _1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var k = 2;
  var j = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var column = 10;
  for (var i = k; i = j; i++){
    cell = spreadsheet.getRange(i,column);
    if (cell.isBlank()) { 
      cell.setValue(0);
    }
  }
}
```

This returns the following error:

> Exception: The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.

I believe this means the getRange function is expecting an input of A1 style cell location, but I'm not certain. I also don't know how to convert to one. Finally I'm not sure that the script will work once I've fixed this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason of your error of `The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.` is due to that you are using Class Spreadsheet with `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`. Class Spreadsheet has no method of `getRange(row, column)`.
- In your for loop, `(var i = k; i = j; i++)` is required to be modified. When you want to modify, please modify to `(var i = k; i <= j; i++)`.
- But, in your script, `setValue` is used in the loop. In this case, the process cost will be high.

When these points are reflected to the sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function _1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ranges = sheet
    .getRange("J2:J" + sheet.getLastRow())
    .getDisplayValues()
    .flatMap(([v], i) => v == "" ? ["J" + (i + 2)] : []);
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue(0);
}
```

- In this script, at first, the values are retrieved from the column "J". And, check each cell and retrieve the a1Notations as an array. And then, the value `0` is put to the a1Notations.
- If your script is directly modified, it becomes as follows.

  ```
    function _1() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var k = 2;
      var j = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
      var column = 10;
      for (var i = k; i <= j; i++) {
        var cell = spreadsheet.getRange(i, column);
        if (cell.isBlank()) {
          cell.setValue(0);
        }
      }
    }
  ```
- If you want to use `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`, you can also use the following modification.

  ```
    function _1() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var k = 2;
      var j = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
      for (var i = k; i <= j; i++) {
        cell = spreadsheet.getRange("J" + i);
        if (cell.isBlank()) {
          cell.setValue(0);
        }
      }
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [getActive()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive)
- [getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet)
- [getRange(a1Notation) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation)
- [getRange(row, column) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

Comment: Thank you for clearly explaining the issues and why your solution works. I can confirm it accomplishes what I intended.

Comment: @Sam Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function zero() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 10, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  vs.forEach(e => {
    if (e[0] == '') {
      e[0] = 0;
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(2, 10, vs.length, 1).setValues(vs).setNumberFormat('0.#####');
}
```